# FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException

Tags: java

When I run this piece of code below I get the following error,

```
FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
        long l = 1000;
        String length = String.format("%1$#8s", (Long)l);

    }
}
```

As per [this doc](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7007868) it's been fixed in jdk7,

> It was a bug that `FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException` was not thrown in the past. This has been fixed in jdk7 via 5063507. This may be something to include in the release notes for jdk7.

I'm running the code against 1.7.0_67-b01 and still see this problem.

Comment: You've misread the bug. If you're getting an exception, then that shows that it *has* been fixed. In an earlier version, it *should* have been thrown but wasn't.

Comment: (If you think it should be valid, please explain what you're trying to achieve.)

Comment: I totally mis-read...Thanks..

Comment: (Long)l Why are you casting a `long` to a `long`?